# Error after updating android studio in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error "Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:" please help me if anyone can.

I haven't tried anything. I just want some solution to this please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to downgrade your platform-tools from version 29 to version 28.
You can find the download links and further information at:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938

How to:
1) Close Android studio.
2) Download platform-tools version 28.
3) Remove platform-tools folder.
4) Unzip the file to `C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
5) Start Android studio again.

Download links:
Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip